# Binding Jquery Datepicker to Vue.JS

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I tried to insert date to database by consuming API through Axios. Date value was selected from jquery datepicker in Vue input form. But in database field date is empty. I assume that jquery datepicker cannot be binded with Vue.JS. perhaps i missed something. Need your help

here's the html code and jquery for datepicker

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>STNK S/D</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker"  value="YY/MM/DDDD" v-model="stnksd" name="stnksd" id="stnksd"  readonly="readonly" > 
         <label><span>{{ stnksd }}</span></label>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input.datepicker").singleDatePicker();
  });

  $.fn.singleDatePicker = function() {
    $(this).on("apply.daterangepicker", function(e, picker) {
      picker.element.val(picker.startDate.format(picker.locale.format));
    });
    return $(this).daterangepicker({
      locale: {
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD' // Change to local formats YYYY-MM-DD - MM-DD-YYYY
      },
      singleDatePicker: true,
      showDropdowns: true,
      autoUpdateInput: false
    });
  };
</script>
```

here's the code for Vue.JS

```
var inputMobile = {
    init: function(){
        this.vueConfig();
        API.auth();
    },
    vueConfig: function(){
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data() {
                return{
                stockSubmit: false,

                stnksd: "",

                  }
            },

            methods: {
                submitStock: function(){
                    let self = this;
                    this.stockSubmit = true;
                    axios({
                        method: 'post',
                        url: urlAddStock,
                        data: {
                            stnksd: this.stnksd,

                        }
                    }).then(res =>{
                        console.log(res.data);

                        if(res.data.message === "Berhasil Menambahkan Data")
                        {
                            self.stockSubmit = false;
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            self.stockSubmit = false;
                        }

                    }, err =>{
                        console.log(err);
                        self.stockSubmit = false;
                    });
                 },
```

Comment: Do not initialize the datepicker outside of Vue's responsibilty. Instead, use the lifecycle hooks provided by Vue (like `created()` and `mounted()`)   and make sure the viewmodel has control over this.

Comment: @connexo how to initialize jquery datepicker inside vue responsibility ?

Comment: Using Jquery with Vue JS is not a really good practice. My advice would be to use a vue JS package like this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker

You can have a look to this github repository to find any components you might need : https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue

Comment: @NelvanBalthazar As mentioned in my comment. Do not init it from the outside (as you're doing now on document.ready), but rather from the inside in a lifecycle hook.

Comment: @connexo how to do it using mounted() or created() could you please give me some example

Comment: I suggest your read the Vue.js documentation (which is really concise and well-written, btw!).